# SQL Join and Sub queries confusion

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT familyname 
FROM dtoohey.patient, DTOOHEY.account, dtoohey.doctor 
WHERE dtoohey.account.patientID = dtoohey.patient.patientid 
  AND dtoohey.doctor.providerno = DTOOHEY.account.providerno 
  AND dtoohey.doctor.name = 'Dr Brian';

SELECT familyname 
FROM dtoohey.patient 
WHERE patientid IN (
          SELECT patientid 
          FROM dtoohey.account 
          WHERE providerno IN (
              SELECT providerno 
              FROM dtoohey.doctor 
              WHERE name = 'Dr Brian'
          )
);
```

What is the difference between these two? Both gives different result.

Comment: Please use the inner join syntax instead of joining in your where clause.

Comment: @Swoorup  Are you talking about execution time or result? Answer was posted by other peoples belong execution plan.

Comment: They are producing different results.

Answer (score 1):

Main difference in your execution plan. Possible this query can be more effective -

```
SELECT familyname
FROM dtoohey.patient p
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM dtoohey.account a
    JOIN dtoohey.doctor d ON d.providerno = a.providerno
    WHERE a.patientID = p.patientid
        AND d.Name = 'Dr Brian'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the times joins are faster than sub-queries but not always, I faced a problem days ago where I had 7 joins and the execution time was taking about 50 seconds, I replaced two joins with sub-queries (the two joins that I suspected was causing the delay) and it went down to 1 second.

Here are some links that will help you:

1. [Join vs. sub-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-subquery)
2. [when to use which](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/62086/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001361223.htm)